# Android: How to make Grid view with clickable grid items and nested views (buttons,Image) by remote(For Android TV)

Tags: android

How to make Grid view with click able grid items and nested views (buttons,Image) by remote(For Android TV)

I just want to click able image and button in grid view item should add to play my list if I navigate on button by Remote navigation not by touch

Thank you!!!

How to navigate through d pad in grid view sub items if grid view item have two sub items image button  and another button

Answer (score 2):

It is no difference between touch screen or remote control for methods like onClickListener or etc.
For remote control, you need to **focus** on the element first, than you can **click** the element.

I have not use the gridView on TV before, but I have used the recyclerView and scrollView. I think they have same situation.

I've try the default simpleAdapter to create the gridView, and it's no problem with the nested views that I can focus and click each grid items after I set the **onItemClickListener** to the gridView.

I guest your problem is that the grid item conflicts with the button in the grid item.
To avoid this situation, you need to set **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** for the container of your custom grid item view. It will block the items statement in that parent layout.

If you want the button change in the different statement, you can give the button this parameter: **android:duplicateParentState="true"**.
That will let the button follow it's parent's statement.

By the way, don't forget to set some changes to different statement for the grid items (background changes or etc), or you will not know which grid item you have focused :P.

Hope this will help you :)

---

PS. The following is the sample code for the custom grid item layout. Maybe the example can help you to understand what I mentioned easily.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**2015.01.06 23:11 update:**

> How to navigate through d pad in grid view sub items if grid view item
>   have two sub items image button and another button

For this case you should not use **OnItemClickListener**. Instead, you should make your grid item **unfocusable** and **unclickable**, and than set **OnClickListener** for both two buttons.

You can set the parameters in your customize adapter for the gridView. In getView method you can set each of the grid item view just like **convertView.focusable(false)** and **convertView.clickable(false)**.
After that, you can set the click listener and give the method you want to do for the buttons in adapter. 
Don't care about the D-pad action. Actually, D-pad will work automatically if there are elements can be focused.

The key point for this question is the conflict between grid item and its child elements. You could have just one part to be focused: grid item (the parent view), or the buttons (the child views).